# Magento 2 display sum of 2 column value of same record

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent

I am creating grid using ui component.
I'm creating it successfully.

But i want to display sum of two column in single field
something like, I have 2 column **(stotal , rtotal)**,
so i want to display **sum of stotal and r total** in one custom column called total.

Anyone have solution for this?

Comment: Are you taking about admin grid?

Comment: yes its in admin grid

Comment: http://prntscr.com/jwa23r  sum of this two column

Comment: I ll udpate you the solution. Give me few minutes.

Comment: Try this solution https://github.com/Galillei/sample_add_columns_to_order_grid and update the column according to your requirement.